# How to make [AllowHtml] and [CaptchaVerify] work together?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, captcha

I'm stuck on a catch 22 here. I have an issue where these two attributes are not working together.  The `[AllowHtml]` attribute on my property works if I remove the `[CaptchaVerify]` attribute from the controller action.

I'm getting the

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client

exception.

**How can I get round this?**

---

Here's my property that should allow html:

```
[AllowHtml]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a comment.")]
public string CommentText
{
    get; set;
}
```

My View looks like this (I've truncated it for this example):

```
@using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers

@using (Html.BeginForm("Article", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CommentText, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.Captcha("Refresh", "Enter the phrase shown above", 4, "Captcha image is required.", false)
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
}
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[CaptchaMvc.Attributes.CaptchaVerify("Captcha is not valid")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Article(ArticleModel model)
{
    // Check the captcha.
    if (ModelState["CaptchaInputText"] != null && ModelState["CaptchaInputText"].Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        ViewBag.CaptchaError = "Please fill in the text above";
    }

    // Rest of my action
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the source code, and found a solution.

Unfortunately they need to make a change on their source code
https://captchamvc.codeplex.com/workitem/11

You can download the source code and make the change your self following the link above, or wait for then to update the source code.

Comment: Excellent. Works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still doing some research, but for now I found this solution, change the web config:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17258129/3202657

Doing this change it will disable all forms requests validations, so **I strongly don't recommend**

I try to add a globalfilter too, but it didn't work:

```
  public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
  {
     filters.Add(new ValidateInputAttribute(false));
  }
```

This library it's a open source, try downloading and debuging the code