# How to allow html to be submitted by a form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have Model where some specific fields are decorated with:

`AllowHtml`

Although that should let that a form field with html input submitted but instead i get this error.

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (Topic=p style=box-sizing...").

What am I missing here? help please...

Comment: This may help yuo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254354/asp-net-mvc-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-cli

Answer (score 0):

By default, the ASP.NET MVC framework checks requests during model binding to determine whether they contain potentially dangerous content as HTML markup. If HTML is detected, model binding throws an error.
If a property is marked with the AllowHtmlAttribute attribute, the ASP.NET MVC framework skips validation for that property during model binding.

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

As per above defintion, you shouldnt get the error if you have properly used the AllowHtml attribute:

**Best Example :**

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/What-is-AllowHtml-attribute-its-Uses-and-Examples-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Hope the above link will surely helpful for you,Kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks.

thanks

karthik

Answer (score 0):

You have to just add **[ValidateInput(false)]** attribute above your controller. This attribute to allowing all HTML

```
 [HttpPost]  
 [ValidateInput(false)]
 public ActionResult AddAgreement(AgreementsModel model)
 {
    //Your code here
 }
```