# MVC - Get Html tag in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a section in my website where I want to send as an email to user when they click on button send. How can I pass the HTML and it's content to controller and then passing it as the message body to smtpClient

I have

```
<div id="mydiv">
<div>
<a>Click Here</a>
</div>

</div>
```

I will like to get all the html and it's content `(<div id="mydiv"><div><a>Click Here</a></div></div>)` when the id mydiv is called from the controller

Comment: You need to use a model for the fields in your contact form. Check the online tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to intercept the click and construct an ajax request that includes the html of your choice. Accept the html as a string argument with a matching name. Then use the smtp client to forward it to the address of your choice.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#button1", {}, function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var x = $("#mydiv").html();

        var options = {
            url: "your url",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                data1: x
            }
        };

        var req = $.ajax(options);

        req.done(function (resp) {
            alert("Email sent");
        });

    });
});
</script>

<div id="mydiv">
<div>
    <a id="button1">Click Here</a>
</div>
</div>


public IActionResult TestAction(string data1)
{
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp_server");
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com");
        mailMessage.To.Add("test@test.com");
        mailMessage.Body = data1;
        mailMessage.Subject = "subject";
        client.Send(mailMessage);

        return null;//or whatever you want
}
```

Comment: should mailMessage.Body = data1;  ?

Comment: data1 returns null

Comment: Please specify POST as the method. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an html editor, check [ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/) for example. and [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-ckeditor-in-mvc-5/) is a  tutorial on how to implement it with mvc
and when you install the CKEDITOR make sure the config [htmlEncodeOutput](https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.htmlEncodeOutput) is true.
If you used it, the action might reject the request because it contains dangerous input, you will have to set the validate input to false, or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254354) for more details