# ASP.Net MVC : A potentially dangerous Request.Files value was detected from the client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have uploaded a file in my asp.net page with filename "Ex&#_17.pdf" then when getting file at backend using Request.Files[0] then getting following error.

A potentially dangerous Request.Files value was detected from the client (filename="Ex&#_17.pdf")

If i changed the file name to following types then it is working fine.

- "Ex&_#_17.pdf"
- "Ex#&_17.pdf"
- "Ex&_17.pdf"
- "Ex#_17.pdf"

I assume that only &# in file name is treated as potentially dangerous.

So, my question is that, is there any other special characters which and produce this error.

I googled this error, but finds nothing.

Comment: do you want to avoid validation in your iis?

Comment: this is actually not a good idea to disable validation. In your front end, you should use javascript to encode all these characters into Html.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, MVC tries to detect suspicious values that are sent to the server, resulting in "*A potentially dangerous value was detected from the client.*" errors.

For example, you are not allowed to send `<script>alert('hello');</script>` in an text input. See [ASP.NET MVC A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client when using a custom modelbinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254354/asp-net-mvc-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-cli) for a similar error.

Because `&#___;` can be used to reference an [HTML Entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity), the filename `Ex&#_17.pdf` is suspect. Here is a chart of these codes (thanks Train): [The HTML Coded Character Set](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html)

You could disable the validation for the file upload:

- I am not sure if attributing the `HttpPostedFileBase` property in the ViewModel with `[AllowHtml]` would work.
- You can also try to mark the Action method with `[ValidateInput(false)]`.

Or use a client side JavaScript to remove or encode suspicious characters in the filename before posting it, as phonemyatt suggested.

Comment: Thanks, i have escaped these characters before posting files.

Answer (score 2):

Your using the syntax for HTML [special characters](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html)

`&#...` are html coded markup sets. I would suggest changing it.